# Code works without borrowing but I can't make it work with borrowing

Tags: rust

I have some code and it works but AFAIK borrowing is made specifically to avoid passing same object in and out of method manually like I did in `split_text` method.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut test = String::from("12345");
    let mut obj1 = Object {
        text: test.as_mut_str(),
        next: None,
    };
    for i in 0..5 {
        obj1 = obj1.split_text(4 - i);
        if let Some(obj) = obj1.next.as_ref() {
            println!("{}", obj.text);
        }
    }
}

struct Object<'a> {
    text: &'a mut str,
    next: Option<Box<Object<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Object<'a> {
    fn split_text(mut self, count: usize) -> Self {
        let tmp = self.text;
        let (part1, part2) = tmp.split_at_mut(count);
        self.text = part1;
        let obj2 = Object {
            text: part2,
            next: None,
        };
        self.next = Some(Box::new(obj2));
        self
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=697dc6a26ac47d7f7028aa0ccf20fa07))

But I can't figure out how to pass borrow checker

```
impl<'a> Object<'a> {
    fn split_text(&'a mut self, count: usize) {
        let tmp = &mut self.text;
        let (part1, part2) = tmp.split_at_mut(count);
        self.text = part1;
        let obj2 = Object {
            text: part2,
            next: None,
        };
        self.next = Some(Box::new(obj2));
    }
}
```

result in the error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `obj1` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         obj1.split_text(4 - i);
   |         ^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `obj1.next` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:28
   |
11 |         obj1.split_text(4 - i);
   |         ---- mutable borrow occurs here
12 |         if let Some(obj) = obj1.next.as_ref() {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^
   |                            |
   |                            immutable borrow occurs here
   |                            mutable borrow later used here

error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.text` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
23 | impl <'a> Object<'a> {
   |       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
24 |     fn split_text(&'a mut self, count:usize) {
25 |         let tmp = &mut self.text;
   |                   -------------- borrow of `self.text` occurs here
26 |         let (part1, part2) = tmp.split_at_mut(count);
   |                              ----------------------- argument requires that `self.text` is borrowed for `'a`
27 |         self.text = part1;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.text` occurs here
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a77f8a9d990e0b2ec4b3747828e97090))

Is there a way to make this code to work?

Comment: Your second code example does not work, because `split_text` does not return `Self` as in the first example. Also please fix your post. Link to the playground instead to the gist `https://play.rust-lang.org/edition=2018&gist=<gist_id>`. Also please use `rustfmt` (in the upper right corner in the playground under tools) to format your code according to the community guidelines.

Comment: Please also address the other issues I listed above in your code. We can't help you if you give us non-working code.

Comment: As I said in my question, I can't make second code example to work without removing borrowing and it is not clear from your comment what I'm supposed to fix. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63d7073bb5791327831de3c6dcf66556

Comment: Please look at my edit and see what I mean.  Also your signature changed between your two code examples, which results in an error I had (the on with that `split_text` does not return `Self` anymore). Second I asked you to format the code properly. Also don't put code and error in the same code block. Please keep that in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are borrowing the object `obj1` mutable in function `split_text` for `'a` lifetime which is up to the end of the `main` function.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut test = String::from("12345");
    let mut obj1 = Object {                             // 'a start
        text: test.as_mut_str(),
        next: None,
    };
    for i in 0..5 {
        obj1 = obj1.split_text(4 - i);                  // borrow for 'a lifetime,
                                                        // Won't work in next iteration
        if let Some(obj) = obj1.next.as_ref() {         // Won't work
            println!("{}", obj.text);
        }
    }
}                                                       // 'a end
```

You want to borrow it mutably only for `split_text` function i.e. for a different (smaller) lifetime - which you can either elide or specify a different one - say `'b`.

```
struct Object<'a> {
    text: &'a str, // no need of mutable slice here
    next: Option<Box<Object<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Object<'a> {
    fn split_text(&mut self, count: usize) { // No lifetime required here
        let (part1, part2) = self.text.split_at(count); // no need of temp var and mutable split here
        self.text = part1;
        let obj2 = Object {
            text: part2,
            next: None,
        };
        self.next = Some(Box::new(obj2));
    }
}
```

Explicit different lifetime version (just for completeness):

```
impl<'a> Object<'a> {
    fn split_text<'b>(&'b mut self, count: usize) {
        let tmp = &mut self.text;
        let (part1, part2) = tmp.split_at(count);
        self.text = part1;
        let obj2 = Object {
            text: part2,
            next: None,
        };
        self.next = Some(Box::new(obj2));
    }
}
```

Also, make something mutable only when required. I changed the mutable slice and split to normal.